# Facing error in apple multitasking code

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Actually I am working for multitasking and facing error please assist me, as I need to work on background application and also in foreground application

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    // Request permission to run in the background. Provide an
    // expiration handler in case the task runs long.
    NSAssert(bgTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid, nil);

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Synchronize the cleanup call on the main thread in case
        // the task actually finishes at around the same time.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            {
                [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task.

        // Synchronize the cleanup call on the main thread in case
        // the expiration handler is fired at the same time.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            {
                [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I believe what you're trying to do will only become available in iOS 4.0, which is still under NDA. Better try your luck in the developer forums in the iPhone Dev Center.

Answer (score 3):

Put in your @interface:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
```

(out from NDA now).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), if you have a developer's account. We can't really answer the os4.0 question because it's under NDA, but all the information you'll need to answer that question is on that page (once logged in).

Comment: Friend I have copied this piece of code from specified link, but facing error in executing it, and how can I define bgtask as it is showing i.e bgtask is not in structure or union.